# Есть ли удобное решение для сложных запросов?

Tags: php, doctrine2

Работая с Doctrine2 я заметил, что с ее помощью очень удобно сохранять данные сущностей, однако с выборками нужно существенно повозиться. Понятно, что это не проблема самой ORM, а скорее вопрос подходов, и все-же хочется найти удобное решение для формирования универсальных и сложных запросов.

Итак, пример будет как всегда самый простой: есть записи, теги к ним, картинки и автор.
Задача тоже простая: получить список категорий.

И по мимо этого есть еще список определенных кейсов по оптимизации и фильтрации:

- Список записей
- Список записей с картинками
- Список записей с тегами
- Список записей с картинками и тегами
- Список записей с картинками, тегами и автором
- Список записей с картинками и тегами, где автор такой-то
- Список записей с картинками и тегами, где автор такой-то и тег такой-то
- Список записей где количество тегов больше 5, а рейтинг автора меньше 100 при условии, в в записи больше 1 картинки.

По сути это все упирается в 1 запрос, "получения списка записей", с фильтрацией и условиями.
Однако реализовать подобное с помощью doctrine2 да и наверное голом SQL с PHP достаточно кодообъемно.

На всякий случай я приведу сюда пример решения от которого я отказался сразу. Это отдельный метод для каждого запроса, например:

```
$this->recordRepository->findList($first, $offset);
$this->recordRepository->findListWithTags($first, $offset);
$this->recordRepository->findListWithTagsAndImages($first, $offset);
$this->recordRepository->findListWithTagsAndImagesAndAuthor($first, $offset);
$this->recordRepository->findListWithTagsAndImagesAndAuthor($first, $offset);
$this->recordRepository->findListWithTagsAndImagesAndAuthorByAuthor($first, $offset, $userId);
$this->recordRepository->findListWithTagsAndImagesAndAuthorByAuthorAndTag($first, $offset, $userId, $tagId);
...
```

В общем таких комбинаций одного запроса может быть весьма много. В качестве преимущества можно рассмотреть удобство тестирования, но вот недостатки весьма перекрывают это дело:
- например findListWithTags и findListWithTagsAndImages не несут в себе ничего для бизнес логики, а только внутреннюю оптимизацию.
- очень сильно разрастается кол-во методов в репозитории
- появляется некая грязь по коду, с теми-же условиями но внутри.

Пока мое решение, что-то вроде:

```
$this->recordRepository->findListByCondition($condition);
```

Где $condition, некий объект собирающий у себя условия. Этот подход выглядит весьма рабочий, однако имеет ряд недостатков:

- Когда мы заполняем $condition нашими условиями, существует возможность дублирования в неких кейсах.
- В репозитории нужно проанализировать $condition, в результате появляется множество условий
- Сложность тестирования.

В общем хотелось бы получить совет или наводку на решение данного вопроса.

Comment: странно, что нет динамической склейки методов, типа там `->findList()->findTags()->findImages`, [tag:CakePHP] к примеру позволяет как по цепочками условия задавать, так и строить имя метода динамически `findListTagsImages()`, ну или около того.

Comment: Добавьте примерный код пары ваших методов. Ваш [прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757474/doctrine-есть-ли-решение-для-оптимальной-выборки-и-поиску-по-ассоциациям) страдает тем же самым.

Comment: а в чем ваш метод плох? у вас 10 комбинаций -> вот и получается 10 разных кейсов. либо же вы можете делать 1 общий метод, который получить огромную пачку всего, что можно, заюзаете кеш и т.д

Comment: @teran, в  cakephp сидит AR. Мой вопрос не совсем из этой области. Если AR плохо дружит с абстракциями, но если в cakephp ввести сущности и репозитории, мы получите ту-же проблему.

Comment: @Nepster что есть AR ? зы: сущности и репозитории там есть.

Comment: @myxaxa, мня беспокоит грязноватый код и сложность в тестировании. Хочется изысканности.

Comment: @svgrafov так вопрос скорее по теории. Что я вам покажу, квери билдер ?  Вот подсуетился, https://pastebin.com/5WELiijE

Comment: @Nepster ничего грязного не вижу. можно написать общий метод. но тогда набор параметров для фильтра придется осуществлять в том месте, где будет вызов. раз вы хотите объявить методы с защитыми параметрами фильтрации - то как их не объявлять - не знаю. в классе EntityRepository доктрины есть реализация магии через _call